# Setting physical channel parameters from an agent

Tags: unetstack

In the startup method of my agent I get the agent ID of the physical agent as:
`phy = agentForService(Services.PHYSICAL)`

Then I have tried different ways to set the powerLevel but usually something like:
`phy.send(new ParameterReq().set(PhysicalChannelParam.powerLevel, -20))`
`phy.send(new ParameterReq().set(PhysicalChannelParam.powerLevel, [-20 -20 -20]))`
`phy.set(PhysicalChannelParam.powerLevel, [-20 -20 -20]`

Neither of them works.
I guess this is because there are multiple physical channels (CONTROL, DATA).
How do I specify which channel type to change the power level of?

EDIT:
A solution was to apparently to change the parameter directly:
`control_channel = phy[1]`
`control_channel.powerLevel = -20`
However, this feels like violating the basic ideas behind Fjåge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `phy[1].powerLevel = -20` syntax is just a syntactic sugar for roughly this:

```
def phy = agentForService(Services.PHYSICAL)
def req = new ParameterReq(phy)
req.setIndex(1)
req.set(PhysicalChannelParam.powerLevel, -20)
def rsp = request(req, 1000)
assert rsp?.get(PhysicalChannelParam.powerLevel) == -20
```

The `req.setIndex(1)` was the magic ingredient you were missing.

Also see: [ParameterReq API docs](http://org-arl.github.io/fjage/javadoc/org/arl/fjage/param/ParameterReq.html).

Comment: Ah, now I understand what the indexing of the ParameterReq referred to. Cheers :) I was a bit surprised that the sugar-way worked inside any agent. Thought it was a feature of the shell agent.

Comment: It is a feature of `AgentID` provided in Groovy, and so it works in all Groovy agents in UnetStack, and is implemented under-the-hood using `ParameterReq` messages. If you're writing a Java agent, there are `UnetAgent` utility methods `get()` and `set()` that can be used instead of the Groovy indexing syntax.